# Update issues in CRUD with Mongo/Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm trying to do a basic update of a user information on my app.

I have my user Schema defined here in it's own model file:

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstname: String,
    lastname: String,
    username: String,
    password: String,
    email: String,
    zip: String,
    bio: String,
    influences: String,
    favBooks: String,
    notWriting: String,
    favHero: String,
    favVillain: String
});
```

The user model is being imported and required in my user route js file.

```
var User = require('../models/userModel');
```

When the user creates their account, only firstname, lastname, email, and password are required. The rest of the fields aren't.

When the user clicks on the button to edit their profile, this is my route for the "show" form of the edit.

```
// edit profile get route
router.get('/:id/edit', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
  // find the right user by id
    User.findById(req.params.id, function(err, foundUser) {
      if (err) throw err
      res.render('editProfile', {currentUser: foundUser});
    });
});
```

It returns the correct (current) user.

On the editprofile html/view (I'm using pug as a template engine so it may look odd), I have this form.

```
form(action='/users/' + currentUser._id + '?_method=PUT', method='POST')
                        .form-row
                            .form-group 
                                label(for="profilePic") Add or change your profile picture
                                input.form-control-file#profilePic(type="file", name='profilePic')
                        .form-row.mt-2
                            .col-sm-6
                                label(for="firstname") First name
                                input.form-control#firstname(type="text", name='firstname')
                            .col-sm-6
                                label(for="lastname") Last name
                                input.form-control#lastname(type="text", name='lastname')
                        .form-row.mt-2
                            .col-sm-6
                                label(for="country") Country/Region
                                select.form-control#country
                                    option United States
                            .col-sm-6
                                label(for="zip") Zip Code
                                input.form-control(type='text', name='zip', placeholder='Zip')
                        .form-row.mt-2
                            .col-sm-12
                                label(for="bio") Bio/Summary
                                textarea.form-control#bio(name="bio", cols="30", rows="10", placeholder="Tell us about you...")
                        .form-row.mt-2
                            label(for="influences") Who are your influences?
                                small.ml-2 (comma separated values only)
                            input.form-control#influences(type='text', name='influences', placeholder='i.e. JK Rowling, Charles Dickens, Sylvia Plath, Stephen King')
                        .form-row.mt-2
                            label(for="favBooks") What are your favorite books?
                                small.ml-2 (comma separated values only)
                            input.form-control#favBooks(type='text', name='favBooks', placeholder='i.e. Ulysses, War and Peace, Emma, The Great Gatsby')
                        .form-row.mt-2
                            label(for="notWriting") When I'm not writing, I'm...
                                small.ml-2 (comma separated values only)
                            input.form-control#notWriting(type='text', name='notWriting', placeholder='i.e. reading, eating, sleeping')
                        .form-row.mt-2
                            label(for="favHero") My favorite hero/heroines are...
                                small.ml-2 (comma separated values only)
                            input.form-control#favHero(type='text', name='favHero', placeholder='i.e. Harry Potter, robinson Crusoe, Sherlock Holmes, Guinevere')
                        .form-row.mt-2
                            label(for="favVillain") My favorite villains are...
                                small.ml-2 (comma separated values only)
                            input.form-control#favVillain(type='text', name='favVillain', placeholder='i.e. Professor Moriarty, Sauron, Dracula, The White Witch')
                        .form-row.mt-2
                            .btn-group.ml-auto
                                a.btn.btn-danger.mr-2.text-white Discard changes
                                button.btn.btn-primary(type='submit') Save profile changes
```

The form is capturing data as I'm able to console log the values with this put/post code in the user route file on the server-side.

```
router.put('/:id', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {

    // find and update the correct user
    var firstname = req.body.firstname;
    var lastname = req.body.lastname;
    var zip = req.body.zip;
    var bio = req.body.bio;
    var influences = req.body.influences;
    var favBooks = req.body.favBooks;
    var notWriting = req.body.notWriting;
    var favHero = req.body.favHero;
    var favVillain = req.body.favVillain;
});
```

I've tried two different methods to update the user with the new information and both aren't working. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. The correct user is being found, it does not console log any errors, but after I run the code and go back into the mongo db and find the user, the old info is still there. Any ideas?

```
return User.update(req.params.id, {firstname: firstname});


    User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, firstname, function(err, foundUser) {
      if(err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        console.log("Updated")
        console.log(foundUser);
      }
    });
    // redirect to user profile page
```

Comment: In your second example for update it looks like you're passing in a string and not an object.  Try `.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, { firstname }, function(err, foundUser) `

Comment: @VtoCorleone yeah, that was it. Thanks!

Comment: Is this working? How about the id being passed as a string? it should be ObjectId()

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in an object as the second parameter instead of a string in your `findByIdAndUpdate` call.

Use

`User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, { firstname }, function(err, foundUser) {`

instead of

`User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, firstname, function(err, foundUser) {`